# Kusto's `parse_json` doesn't work on custom dimensions

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer

I'm hoping to be able to analyze structured data stored in a custom dimension of a custom telemetry event emitted to application insights, and getting some weird behavior. It seems like the JSON can't be parsed normally, but if I pass it through `strcat` it is able to parse the json just fine.

```
customEvents 
| where name == "PbConfigFilterComponentSaved"
| take 1
| project 
    jsonType=gettype(customDimensions.Json), 
    parsedType=gettype(parse_json(customDimensions.Json)), 
    strcatType=gettype(strcat('', customDimensions.Json)),
    strcatParsedType=gettype(parse_json(strcat('', customDimensions.Json)))
```

Result:

```
jsonType:         string
parsedType:       string
strcatType:       string
strcatParsedType: dictionary
```

Is there a better approach to getting parse_json to work on this kind of value?

### Update

In case it's in any way relevant, here's the value of `customDimensions.Json`:

```
{"filterComponentKey":"CatalystAgeRange","typeKey":"TemporalConstraint","uiConfig":{"name":"Age","displayMode":"Age"},"config":{"dateSelector":"pat.BirthDTS"},"disabledForScenes":false,"disabledForFilters":false}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Could you please demonstrate a sample record that isn't parsed correctly?
2. *Speculating (before seeing the data):* Have you verified the final paragraph [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction) doesn't apply to your case?

> It is somewhat common to have a JSON string describing a property bag in which one of the "slots" is another JSON string. […] In such cases, it is not only necessary to invoke `parse_json` twice, but also to make sure that in the second call, `tostring` will be used. Otherwise, the second call to `parse_json` will simply pass-on the input to the output as-is, because its declared type is `dynamic`.

Comment: I updated my question with the JSON that's getting parsed. It's pretty standard stuff. Initially I thought that paragraph didn't apply because my JSON doesn't contain properties which contain encoded JSON. But I think the final sentence still applies because `customDimensions` is effectively pre-parsed JSON, so even though `gettype(customDimensions.Json)` tells me it's a `string` there must be a difference between its _declared_ type and its actual type at runtime. So wrapping `customDimensions.Json` in `tostring()` is a better workaround than `strcat`.

Answer (score 2):

The type of `customDimensions` is `dynamic` and so accessing a property like `customDimensions.json` from it will return a string typed as `dynamic`.

You have to explicitly cast it as string and then parse it:

```
todynamic(tostring(customDimensions.json)).property
```

I think the ["Notes" section in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction#example) is exactly the issue, as mentioned by [Yoni L.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55624405/221042) in the previous answer.